# Why does long shows wrong output in finding second maximum of three integers?

Tags: c++

I am a novice to CP and while I was doing this problem of finding the second maximum among three numbers I wrote this code which however works for int but doesn't work for long even though they are the same data types.

**Input Format:**

- The first line contains the number of triples, N.
- The next N lines which follow each have three space separated integers.

**Input Used:**

3

1 2 3

10 15 5

100 999 500

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
       int n;
       cin >>n ;
       while(n--){
          long a,b,c,d;//if i change long to int output is correct  
          scanf("%i%i%i",&a,&b,&c);
          d=min(max(a,b),max(a,c));
          printf("%i\n",d);// outputs 1 \n 10 \n 100 \n(\n means new line)
     }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: More related to your problem, please [get a good C++ book or two or three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and learn C++ properly.

Comment: And no, `long` (or rather `long int` as its full name is) might be an integer just like `int`, but they are not really the same types.

Comment: Why are you mixing use of `cin` and `scanf`?

Comment: Enable the warnings when you compile...

Comment: You could have simply used `cout` and not have to specify types in a format string.  You don't know what the values really are due to possibly using an incorrect format string in `printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because you're using the wrong [specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf). `%i` is for `int`s, but `%li` is for `long`s.